# Django - display list as text block without spacing

Tags: django

Is there a way to display a list as a block of text. But remove the additional line spacing if you perform the following,

```
<pre>
{% for config_line in response.config.cmd %}
    {{ config_line }}
{% endfor %}
</pre>
```

Ideally I want to keep this logic inside the template.

Comment: Use 'join' filter.

Comment: Also you might want to switch <pre> tag to <div>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join) template tag.

Usage is very simple:

```
<pre>
{{ response.config.cmd|join:"" }}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove spaces from the template loop:

```
<pre>
{% for config_line in response.config.cmd %}{{ config_line }}{% endfor %}
</pre>
```